# "undefined" property, when trying to read object's property outside of subscribe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in angular and working on spring+angular project, I have 2 classes called questions and answers.

questions.ts

```
export class Questions {

    private questionDescription: string;
    private id: string;
    private answers: Answers[] = [];
```

// getter setters

answers.ts

```
export class Answers {

    private answerDescription: string;
    private isVisible: boolean;
    private id: string;
    private voteCounter: number;
```

// getter setters

In my component.ts,i fetch the data from webservice. Here's my service;

```
base_url: string = "http://localhost:8080";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getQuestion(id: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Questions>> {
    return this.http.get<Questions>(this.base_url + "/question" + "/" + id, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

This is my component ;

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private restService: RestcallService) { }

  public id: string;
  public question: Questions ;
  public answers: Answers[] = [];
```

ngOnInit() {

```
this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.restService.getQuestion(this.id).subscribe(response => {
  if (response.status == 200) {
    this.question = new Questions("");
    Object.assign(this.question, response.body);
    this.answers = this.question._answers;
  }
})
```

}

After the line "this.answers=this.question._answers" , i use "answers" array in my component.html with [ngModel)] and it works, but i can't read property values of answer array outside of subscribe method,i have a button and this button calls "results()" function on click. I need to perform some calculations after reading object properties but i can't read. Below code prints "undefined" in console.

```
 results() {

    console.log(this.answers[0]._answerDescription); // prints undefined

  }
```

When i change the method like this;

```
results() {

    console.log(this.answers); // prints the array in console

 }
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: show format of answers array

Comment: In your class there is *answerDescription* but you want to get *_answerDescription*. It could be the problem, but if you could show your array that would be helpful.

Comment: @Natixco its a private property, thats why im calling _answerDescription method.

Comment: @Mamta here's the result after  "console.log(this.answers)" ;                             `0: {id: "523046f9-5eb3-4b52-9529-f74fe7d339d8", answerDescription: "1", voteCounter: 1, visible: false}
1: {id: "5fdd6645-3bba-46dc-88d6-3e7d994c51a1", answerDescription: "242", voteCounter: 1, visible: false}
2: {id: "1e78716d-82c7-4ed1-88ec-210f3e959cb1", answerDescription: "22", voteCounter: 2, visible: false}`

Comment: So did you try without the underscore? because I can't see one in the jsons...

Comment: then why _answerDescription it should be answerDescription

Comment: @Natixco Yes, when i try without underscore it gives an error : Property 'answerDescription' is private and only accessible within class 'Answers'

Comment: Then make it public? Or if you dont have any special needs you could use interface instead of class.

Comment: @Natixco i make it public and now it works without underscore, but i don't understand why i can't read the value with getters and setters ,

Comment: @Natixco  set _answerDescription(newVal: string) {
        this.answerDescription = newVal;
    }
    get _answerDescription(): string {
        return this.answerDescription;
    }

Comment: They are methods. Write () at the end of the line like: ```this.answers[0]._answerDescription()```

Comment: @Natixco when i write () at the end it gives an error : "This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures" . In typescript we don't need "()" to call getter setter. i still don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Oh okay. I don't know either what could be the problem.